# How to use shouldForwardProps in styled-components with object syntax and TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, styled-components

I've tried everything but can't figure out the syntax ([here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAZxgTwDYFMAmcBmUIhwDkSaWAtAMYGQB26tMCRA3AFBvW1JwBCAggGUAogH0AwgHkAcgDEAkgHE4AXjgBvNnEQALCAFdUmWdADuAQyiYACvjAAuOAAot2uGDuOkUYLQDmADSu2pjoOOaGMABq5qjAmOYw0LK0jk4eEA6IMD7+AJSqAHxwAEYQEBjmtK4FKsUZYHAAhCpqRMAIgiCxqOIQjOa+6FBEcABkY3Ch4ZExcQlJUCnpdnlBAL7sbAD023DQwH6+sZz9PAAqOr5+qtlkmAB0mMAAbgA8mtodXT19A0NQRxlCroKrsdaFJxOdRwb7dVC9fowQb0KBwda1YrQ1xgcyYZ7+Rxw35IlHDOAAfjgAEYAExwRxEakANjAAA84ABmWnsohBEIdMCoczIRk4DBsvmuWKHWjyGDoEAIRmUBgKkYbPJ5LZcC5Xfz0tSkDCYFzaIjPF5S7QCEQSGQKRRsPIfVzEhF-ZEAoHlSq0cGQ6GwzrwxH-VHozHOT7uPEEvxEkMk8Pkql0hnEFnsrk8yX8qaC4Wi4ji9B56VxPxyhVKlVq4ZSjHaji6+CXa6c27GrCuJ6vV1uYM-D2k72lX2g-2uCFQmHusNeiMYorR4Kx-HXRPDhdktFp+mMrMc7m8-MChBCkViiXWtwyqvyxXK4iqxgN-NN3umYAwHR-HCHE4tpiFIchKM2pzcG2+p+AALF2KAmr2loDm486eruPogmC06FA836-v+gHAfaYGKHks5DqGGEApGK7YoOuIboSVHJouqY0gemasseua3uel7FkQpbloO97Vk+dZvhq05ajqZzQdcACsCH3PhP5-v0AF+EBQggQ64F9u8MboaOqJYX6AaUaZKZosudSrtoTHxlu1FmRx6aHjxOanq4zwXkW15lre4mPrWL71jJTYsEAA) is a TS Playground):

```
const BASE_CONFIG = {
  shouldForwardProp: (
    prop: string,
    defaultValidatorFn: (prop: string) => boolean
  ) => prop !== 'isSmallContainer' && defaultValidatorFn(prop),
};

const Thing = styled(
  'div',
  BASE_CONFIG
)<{
  isSmallContainer: boolean;
}>(({ isSmallContainer }) => ({
  padding: isSmallContainer ? 12 : '16px 32px',
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
}));
```

> Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.

My original definition without `shouldForwardProps`:

```
const Thing = styled.div<{
  isSmallContainer: boolean;
}>(({ isSmallContainer }) => ({
  padding: isSmallContainer ? 12 : '16px 32px',
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
}));
```

Where do I put the config and also have TypeScript syntax and object notation (as opposed to styled-components template strings)?

Another attempt:

```
const Thing = styled
  .div<{
    isSmallContainer: boolean;
  }>(({ isSmallContainer }) => ({
    padding: isSmallContainer ? 12 : '16px 32px',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }))
  .withConfig(BASE_CONFIG);
```

> This expression is not callable. Type 'never' has no call signatures.

```
const Thing = styled
  .div<{
    isSmallContainer: boolean;
  }>.withConfig(BASE_CONFIG)(({ isSmallContainer }) => ({
    padding: isSmallContainer ? 12 : '16px 32px',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }));
```

> An instantiation expression cannot be followed by a property access.

Haven't figured it out yet.

```
const Thing = styled.withConfig(BASE_CONFIG).div<{
  isSmallContainer: boolean;
}>(({ isSmallContainer }) => ({
  padding: isSmallContainer ? 12 : '16px 32px',
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
}));
```

> Property 'withConfig' does not exist on type 'StyledInterface'.

Comment: A lot of the examples use outdated APIs, like [this](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/900).

Answer (score 1):

In all the APIs that you've used here, you've used them incorrectly. I've annotated the mistakes you've made in [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAZxgTwDYFMAmcBmUIhwDkSaWAtAMYGQB26tMCRA3AFBvW1JwBCAggGUAogH0AwgHkAcgDEAkgHE4AXjgBvNnEQALCAFdUmWdADuAQyiYACvjAAuOAAot2uGDuOkUYLQDmADSu2pjoOOaGMABq5qjAmOYw0LK0jk4eEA6IMD7%20AJSqAHxwAEYQEBjmtK4FKsUZYHAAhCpqRMAIgiCxqOIQjOa%206FBEcABkY3Ch4ZExcQlJUCnpdnlBAL7sbAD023DQwH6%20sZz9PAAqOr5%20qtlkmAB0mMAAbgA8mtodXT19A0NQRxlCroKrsdaFJxOdRwb7dVC9fowQb0KBwda1YrQ1y7dzmTDPfyOOG-JEo4ZwAD8cAAjAAmOCOIg0gBsYAAHnAAMx0jlEILaXGXdBwFBgEUQHB4gnXWG0UU6EVxEpQSzIWEIOAAA28ssm6nWcAAPnAAAxaxAQODIAxwShVODoYAwRVohDoeDO0VWgBewyt0Dg5myuT8rjA%20MJfmJnXhiP%20qKpcAARPSOcnGcRWRzubz2fzXM8EGBUOZkEycBh8wKg3E-LR5DB0CAEEzKAwmyMNnk8lsuBcrv4GWpSBhMC5tERni8C4K9sLcPpaJQYMB%20qLzABrdCa-qodX9EWWPz6EAdy12qpEeDI7d8IRiKRyJQ4vYCEQSGQKZRsPIfVwkgifzIgCQLlJUtDgpC0Iaj8QFkgC6KYs4nxwLiEYykSsFxsB5JotS9KZsybKcjyfI1kKiqisg4r7FKGFRnKCpKsAKpqhq2q6v44waIaJrmheNr6Je8pOi6FLup6N6%20v6%20xosGXFhtoDHXDGcHxiBibUqmeYZky2akXms5TB0JZlhWVbGbEhwNk2LZth2wwFhivYcP28CXNcXK3KOWCuE8rz-m42GkgmwxgSCYKuBCUIwoBGl4UhRQocEaF7CpWHxbhiEEQy%20kkbm5GpZRIpihK9GRrKvjMXAyqqlA6odJxOR6rxxpmhaCBWkJImOs6rqIB6sLSXAfr4HJQYhtcqUZdGIXwWF%20Epmm7J6VmBVkdWqVFmZ5bEJW6BbcF1n1o2zatsQ7aME5NYua%20cDSBA8CCPoYCQLAWClOq-DWPI90PKY-V-DghxOO%20j5fkormnNwHmDn4AAsPkoGO-nTkFbhZQhqIRRB7DaBC-2Ay6wOg%20Dn7PooBTiFUtBPZeCKTX4DDDMAlCuLF80JYhGLJdiwXoZVmWxqFmkUrlREGYVR1uCV1G0ZK0qMdV4m1ax9WNZqOotdx%20p8R1gm2vaon9RJQ1ekko2yYGCk60pbizWpOHY%20Ly26ZLG1GTWISmaWe1EAdMvaCdtnnQ511dtFPZ9mccPXAArMj9xOMm07JnkOx7ADQP9CDfhgw%20FPfgUcsRqqLZBlAIq%20NQUBVyubDZyTuegzCCB6IYxhmJYNieM4DTIQ0qitCmWOLRm1LhKg7qZjk%20gihimdwPwqBV-i6r2gin2%20dgxM6Nq04Wsep4dgEcB0%20f6CfZbm%20oEGfgokvAXvJouJfCLC1i4CpTgaCkFL4TD4Y8v64z-jFGCwDEq8zqClOcStVJc2ylpWkeV1o5k2sZOWZU6LwO4irKidV2JNW1qGHiBp2oCS6taI2DoxIDUksNb0Vtxo2ymv4cMQs5qQJym7dMHt0Fe0LL7cy%201LI1hDmdeyl1HKRxciwIAA) TS Playground link.
But I'll add it here as well -

```ts
// original
const Thing = styled.div<{
  isSmallContainer: boolean;
}>(({ isSmallContainer }) => ({
  // padding: isSmallContainer ? 12 : '16px 32px',
  // The type of padding in the library is `string & {} | 0` so you can either set it to zero or a string
  padding: isSmallContainer ? "12px" : '16px 32px',
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
}));

const Thing2 = styled(
  'div',
  // The function takes only one argument so can't take BASE_CONFIG
  // BASE_CONFIG 
)<{
  isSmallContainer: boolean;
}>(({ isSmallContainer }) => ({
  // padding: isSmallContainer ? 12 : '16px 32px',
  // The type of padding in the library is `string & {} | 0` so you can either set it to zero or a string
  padding: isSmallContainer ? "12px" : '16px 32px',
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
}));

const Thing3 = styled
  .div<{
    isSmallContainer: boolean;
  }>(({ isSmallContainer }) => ({
    // padding: isSmallContainer ? 12 : '16px 32px',
    // The type of padding in the library is `string & {} | 0` so you can either set it to zero or a string
    padding: isSmallContainer ? "12px" : '16px 32px',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }))
  // Not Supported by API
  // .withConfig(BASE_CONFIG);

const Thing4 = styled
  .div<{
    isSmallContainer: boolean;
  }>
  // .withConfig(BASE_CONFIG) Cannot call a generic
  (({ isSmallContainer }) => ({
    // padding: isSmallContainer ? 12 : '16px 32px',
    // The type of padding in the library is `string & {} | 0` so you can either set it to zero or a string
    padding: isSmallContainer ? "12px" : '16px 32px',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }));

const Thing5 = styled("div")
// .withConfig(BASE_CONFIG) // The params are incorrect
.withConfig({ shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop === "isSmallContainer" ? false : true })
// Already called styled with `div` argument, no need to call again
// .div<{
//   isSmallContainer: boolean;
// }>
<{isSmallContainer: boolean}>(({ isSmallContainer }) => ({
  // padding: isSmallContainer ? 12 : '16px 32px',
  // The type of padding in the library is `string & {} | 0` so you can either set it to zero or a string
  padding: isSmallContainer ? "12px" : '16px 32px',
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
}));
```

Comment: That doesn't quite work. `Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type '{}'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{}'.`

Comment: @Alien There seems to be a mismatch in the version you'd asked a solution for, and the version I'd provided a solution for. Check my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76814354/how-to-use-shouldforwardprops-in-styled-components-with-object-syntax-and-typesc/76814764#comment135422735_76816146) down below. I should've clarified the version first.

Answer (score 0):

```
const BASE_IGNORED_PROPS: Array<string | number | symbol> = [
  'isSmallContainer',
];

const BASE_CONFIG: StyledConfig<
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  StyledComponentPropsWithRef<React.ComponentType<any>>
> = {
  shouldForwardProp: (
    prop: string | number | symbol,
    defaultValidatorFn: (prop: string | number | symbol) => boolean
  ) => !BASE_IGNORED_PROPS.includes(prop) && defaultValidatorFn(prop),
};

const Thing = styled.div(({ theme }) => ({
  flex: '0 1 100%',
}));

const ThingInner = styled(Flex).withConfig(BASE_CONFIG)<{
  isSmallContainer: boolean;
}>(({ isSmallContainer }) => ({
  width: '100%',
  padding: isSmallContainer ? 12 : 32,
  paddingBottom: 0,
}));
```

Comment: It looks like you're using an older version of `styled-components`, most likely, any `5.x.x` version with `@types/styled-components`. Starting from `v6`, the library `styled-components` [provides its own types and recommends](https://styled-components.com/releases#v6.0.0-rc.5) to remove the `@types/styled-components`. The solution that I'd added uses `v6`, that's probably the reason for a mismatch and why you've types like `StyledConfig` & `StyledComponentPropsWithRef`.